# Maximize resource utilization given multiple types of resources and specific mixtures of resources per task

Tags: algorithm, optimization

### Given

You have some very large number of possible tasks, each of which requires the use of some subset of possible resources from a large number of possible resources.

Each task has an associated resource cost:

#### Task 1

- 1 gold
- 2 silver

#### Task 2

- 2 gold
- 1 bronze

#### Task 3

- 1 bronze

And you have a set of available resources:

#### Resources

- 3 gold
- 2 bronze

### Problem

Choose a subset of tasks, any of which may be performed more than once, that makes the "best use" of *all* available resources. In this case, perhaps we would choose Task 2 and Task 3, since it leaves us with only 1 gold remaining. We cannot perform Task 1 because we have no silver.

### Questions

This seems like some kind of optimization problem, but I'm not sure at all what this problem would be "called". Is there some fancy name for this that I could look up to guide me in the search for possible solutions? Are there straightforward algorithms out there that solve this? Is it solvable in a reasonable amount of time? Are there some good heuristic approaches?

### Notes

- The problem as shown implies that resources may be weighted differently (i.e. it's worse to be left with 1 gold than with 1 bronze), but that's not necessarily an issue. The solution mustn't account for this, but it would be an interesting extension.
- The tasks and resources need not be integer values, but I'm not sure if that changes the problem significantly.

Comment: This is an example of the utility maximization problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_maximization_problem

Comment: Isn't it just finding a task with maximum value limited by the value of the resources?

Comment: @quinxorin Hmm... that does seem kind of close? But it looks like in that problem, the consumer only has one resource to spend: money. It's the utility that changes between the tasks. In my case, the consumer has various things (money, time, eggs, wood), and the "consumption bundles" require things other than just money.

Comment: Just to clarify: It seems you are saying that you are only allowed to do each task once, and the goal is to minimize the number of resources left at the end? (Rather than, say, maximizing the number of tasks you get done)

Comment: @Tengiz No, not quite. You may choose *more than one task* (and potentially the same task more than once, although I didn't mention that in the question). As a result, a single task may only make use of a fraction of the available resources. And the tasks themselves don't necessarily have any intrinsic "value".

Comment: @RussellZahniser Sorry I wasn't entirely clear. You may potentially do the same task more than once. And yes, the goal is to minimize the remaining resources, not to maximize the number of tasks performed. I've edited the problem statement a bit to try to make it more obvious that tasks can be performed more than once.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this problem is np hard as presented. A greedy algorithm would do pretty well, but when it's all said and done if you want an ideal solution you're going to have an unacceptably high complexity.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus +1 That's a helpful comment. Looks like I'll be aiming to get reasonable results rather than "the right answer".

Comment: If your goal is to minimize available resources, rather than maximize number of tasks, then my original suggestion of a utility optimization problem is a bad fit.

Comment: @Bitwise Very good point. In my case, it *would* be acceptable to use resource fractions. I didn't really think about that when formulating the problem, but if that helps make it easier to solve then that's great! I'll update the question a bit. Does that invalidate the knapsack solution below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds just like a multiple knapsack problem - the only thing you need to change is to assign each item value that is equal to the sum of the items it use, then it becomes a standard knapsack since while maximizing the sum, the remainder is minimized.

Comment: +1 This sounds like a good approach to take. Does this solution work for fractional values of resources and task costs? For instance, a task may cost 1.2 gold and 0.8 bronze, and if I have 1.3 gold and 0.9 bronze available I can do it.

Comment: I don't see why you can't as long as the numbers are rational - just multiply them with the Least Common Multiple should be good. The case of irrational has never occurred to me, so I cannot really say if there's any complexity there. Are you talking about taking fractions of an item as in fractional knapsack problems?

Comment: No, not fractions of an item. It would still be a 0-1 knapsack problem (from my preliminary reading). Just fractional resource and task amounts. But you're exactly right -- it's fairly easy to convert to integer (at least approximately) by just multiplying by a large number and rounding the result. If we *did* want to say "getting rid of gold is more important than getting rid of silver", would that mean that each resource becomes an additional dimension of the knapsack problem? It seems like that would quickly get out of hand in terms of complexity.

Comment: By the way, I really like this approach because it's exactly backward of the way I was thinking about the problem. I was thinking of "allocating resources to tasks", but this formulates it as a "do tasks to use up resources". Neat.

Comment: Thanks! The complexity would be daunting as it is after all a knapsack problem to solve, but there might be libraries for faster computation. @Tyler Durden's answer seems right too, and I think that might be a great direction to go into since this does sound like a packing problem, and linear programming is pretty deeply studied too.

Comment: In this question, what if you have consider each "Resource" as a packaged-deal? So your jobs is to buy the best combination of resources. In this case, you have multiple Resources: such that Resource1 has 2 golds and 3 bronzes, Resource2 has 4 golds and 1 bronze, and Resource3 has 3 golds and 6 bronze. How do choose what the optimal set of resources that you will buy and what task is assigned to what resource.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a type of *set packing*. It is also known as the "flight crew problem". You have a certain number of pilots, engineers, stewards, etc., and different planes which require different assortments of each type of crew. Normally with the flight crew problem you are looking for an exact assignment between personnel and planes, but here we want to maximize the personnel utilization by selecting different types of planes (which are "tasks" in the post).

In any case, the way these problems, which are NP-hard, are solved is by exhaustive search using **mixed integer linear programming**. See [Sandia survey of MILP](http://www.cs.sandia.gov/opt/survey/mip.html) or [MIT Aeronautics page on MILP](http://acl.mit.edu/milp/).

There is a package [SYMPHONY](https://projects.coin-or.org/SYMPHONY) which includes set partitioning and packing solvers which do this.

Comment: +1 Would that package be able to handle the case of non-integer resources and tasks? I'm guessing the fact that you refer to it as a mixed integer linear programming problem implies that it would not be able to extend to that possibility.